# How to fix my game's jumping?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I wanted to create a game where I can move my player tile by tile. I have no idea how to make it jump and how to make it smooth.
This is my code so far:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class PlayerScript : MonoBehaviour {

    /*
     * TILE BY TILE MOVEMENT
     * */

    private bool isMoving = false;
    private bool isJumping = false;
    private Vector3 targetPosition = new Vector3();
    private Vector3 prevPosition = new Vector3();
    public static bool canMove = true;
    private Rigidbody2D rb2D;

    void Start(){
        prevPosition = transform.position;
        rb2D = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D> ();
    }

    public void Move(string moveDirection){
        if (isMoving == false && canMove == true) {

            isMoving = true;

            switch (moveDirection.ToLower()) {
            case "left":
                prevPosition = transform.position;
                targetPosition = prevPosition + new Vector3(-2,0,0);
                targetPosition.x = Mathf.Round(targetPosition.x);
                break;
            case "right":
                prevPosition = transform.position;
                targetPosition = prevPosition + new Vector3(2,0,0);
                targetPosition.x = Mathf.Round(targetPosition.x);
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    public void CancelMove(){
        targetPosition = prevPosition;
        Debug.Log("Canceled move");
    }

    void Update(){

        if (isMoving == false) {
            //Checks if there is ground
            RaycastHit2D hit;
            hit = Physics2D.Raycast (transform.position, -Vector2.up, 1.2f, 1 << LayerMask.NameToLayer("Ground"));
            Debug.DrawRay (transform.position, -Vector2.up* 1.2f);

            RaycastHit2D hitSideRight;
            hitSideRight = Physics2D.Raycast (transform.position, Vector2.right, 1.2f, 1 << LayerMask.NameToLayer("Ground"));
            Debug.DrawRay (transform.position, Vector2.right* 1.2f);

            RaycastHit2D hitSideLeft;
            hitSideLeft = Physics2D.Raycast (transform.position, -Vector2.right, 1.2f, 1 << LayerMask.NameToLayer("Ground"));
            Debug.DrawRay (transform.position, -Vector2.right* 1.2f);

            if((hitSideLeft.collider != null && hitSideLeft.collider.tag != "Box") || (hitSideRight.collider != null && hitSideRight.collider.tag != "Box")){
                CancelMove();
                Debug.Log("Can't move");
            }

            if (hit.collider != null || hit.collider == null){

                if (Input.GetAxisRaw ("Horizontal") > 0 && hitSideRight.collider == null) {
                    Move ("right"); 
                }

                if (Input.GetAxisRaw ("Horizontal") < 0 && hitSideLeft.collider == null) {
                    Move ("left");
                }

                if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space)){
                    rb2D.AddForce(new Vector2(0,800));
                }

            }
        } else {
            if( transform.position.x != targetPosition.x )
            {
                // Move this object towards the target position
                transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, targetPosition, Time.deltaTime * 5f);
            }
            else
            {
                isMoving = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This script is attached to the player. The player has a rigidbody2D and a boxCollider2D: https://i.stack.imgur.com/sEV5b.jpg

Comment: This is the best I came up with: `if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space)){
     if(facingRight){
      transform.position = transform.position + new Vector3(2,2,0);
     } else {
      transform.position = transform.position + new Vector3(-2,2,0);
     }

    }`

Comment: _[Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help)_

Comment: Maybe you should ask [here](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/).